# Nativescript listview infinite scrolling

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I want to implement in my Listview component infinite scroll with the loading indicator.
Need code for native-script vue and I don't want to use RadListView.

Comment: Use [loadMoreItems](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_list_view_.listview#loadmoreitemsevent) event which should be triggered when you reach end of list view, hit your API & add more items in the event.

Comment: I know this event, but how can trigger that event when reach end of list? List view not have scroll event.

Comment: I guess you didn't understand the event then, you don't have to trigger it. You have to listen to the event. It's triggered automatically when there are no items to display, irrespective of scroll.

Comment: thanks a lot, i solved

Answer (score 3):

Use [loadMoreItems](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_list_view_.listview#loadmoreitemsevent) event which should be triggered when you reach end of list view, hit your API & add more items in the event.